# What is the best way to change the formatting of a GridView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to simply change the background color of a row in a GridView based on the value in one of the GridView cells. I have two functions. The first one hits my database and creates a `DataTable` from the database data. The `DataTable` is then used as the datasource for my `GridView`. Here is the code:

```
  Protected Sub FillMipDataGridOnReqNoSearch()
            Dim ReqNumber As String = Me.txtReqNo.Text
            Try
                Dim DbConnection As New DevConnection()
                Dim Da As New SqlDataAdapter()

                                Using DbConnection.Conn
                    DbConnection.Conn.Open()
                    Using SqlCmd As New SqlCommand()
                        With SqlCmd
                            .Connection = DbConnection.Conn
                            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                            .CommandText = "MyStoredProcedure"
                            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = ReqNumber                         End With
                        Using Da
                            Da.SelectCommand = SqlCmd
                            Using Dt As New DataTable()
                                Da.Fill(Dt) 'populates the dataset
                                Gv_MipData.DataSource = Dt
                                Gv_MipData.DataBind()

                                'the following three lines pass the cell indeces for each dateTime cell that needs to be formatted
                                ShortenDateTimeStrings(4) 'date from cell
                                ShortenDateTimeStrings(5) 'date to cell
                                ShortenDateTimeStrings(11) 'date submitted cell
                            End Using
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Sub
```

The second function is the `GridView`'s `RowDataBound` event handler. Here is the code:

```
  Protected Sub Gv_MipData_DataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles Gv_MipData.DataBound

        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim ApprovalStatus As String = e.Row.Cells(9).Text
            If ApprovalStatus = "D" Then
                e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

The above code breaks in the `FillMipDataGridOnReqNoSearch()` function on the `Gv_MipData.DataBind()` line. It catches this exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs'.

I tried changing the parameter `e` in the `RowDataBound` event handler to the type `EventArgs`, but it threw this error:

> 'Row' is not a member of 'System.EventArgs'.

I know I've gotten off-track somewhere. Any suggestions?

**Update: The Markup for the GridView**

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gv_MipData" AllowSorting="true" runat="server" CssClass="GridViewStyle"
                                PageSize="30" Width="100%" AllowPaging="true" OnRowCommand="Gv_MipData_RowCommand">
                                <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />
                                <EmptyDataRowStyle CssClass="EmptyRowStyle" />
                                <PagerSettings Position="TopAndBottom" />
                                <PagerStyle CssClass="PagerStyle" />
                                <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" />
                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />
                                <Columns>
                                    <asp:TemplateField>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="GvBtnApprove" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Style='display: block;
                                                width: 100px;' CommandName="Approve" CssClass="buttonlggrid" Text="Approve">
                                            </asp:LinkButton>
                                            <asp:LinkButton ID="GvBtnDeny" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" Style='display: block;
                                                width: 100px;' CommandName="Deny" CommandArgument="<%#Container.DataItemIndex %>"
                                                CssClass="buttonlggrid" Text="Deny">
                                            </asp:LinkButton>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
                                </Columns>
                            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Your event handler looks good, the parameters should be `sender as object, e as GridViewRowEventArgs`. However, your GridView `Gv_MipData` is expecting `e as EventArgs` as the method signature. My guess is that `Gv_MipData` is not a GridView, but some other class. Is the `Gv_MipData` declared in code or is it added in the Designer page?

Try and find the constructor for `Gv_MipData` and post it.

Comment: @ElroySkimms I have updated the question. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I see it now. You are Handling the event GridView.Databound, but using the method signature for GridView.RowDataBound. Try changing `Handles Gv_MipData.DataBound` to `Handles Gv_MipData.RowDataBound`

Comment: @ElroySkimms Okay, that is working a bit better. It isn't throwing the exception now. However, it is also not changing the background color of the row even though the value in question is set to what it is supposed to trigger the color change. Would you happen to know why?

Comment: I would step through the code and see what the actual contents of Cells(9) is. There might be HTML markup in there somewhere that is throwing things off.

Comment: @ElroySkimms I am a total idiot. You're right; I was using the wrong index value. I have looked at this for way too long. Anyway, it works now. Thanks a lot!